# Postgres recursive with o PL: how many groups are there?

Tags: postgresql, recursion, relationship

I' ve got 2 tables:
Table1: ID_ELEMENT integer
Just one field with the list of the people who I'm interested in.

Relation_table: ID_ELEMENT integer, ID_SECONDARY_ELEMENT integer

```
create table Table1 (ID_Element integer);
create table Relation_table (ID_Element integer,ID_SECONDARY_ELEMENT integer);
```

ID_SECONDARY_ELEMENT could not be present in Table1.

All the elements with a relation (as first or second member in Relation_table, no difference) belongs to the same group.

I want to know how many Groups of elements are there and who belongs to any group.

Example:
Table1: 1,2,3,4,5,6,9,11
Relation_table: (1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,1),(4,6),(5,777),(5,898),(11,9)

```
|id_element |
|-----------|
|1          |
|2          |
|3          |
|4          |
|5          |
|6          |
|9          |
|11         |


|id_element |id_secondary_element|
|-----------|--------------------|
|1          |2                   |
|1          |3                   |
|1          |4                   |
|2          |1                   |
|4          |6                   |
|5          |777                 |
|5          |898                 |
|11         |9                   |
insert into  Table1 values (1);
insert into  Table1 values (2);
insert into  Table1 values (3);
insert into  Table1 values (4);
insert into  Table1 values (5);
insert into  Table1 values (6);
insert into  Table1 values (9);
insert into  Table1 values (11);

insert into Relation_table values (1,2);
insert into Relation_table values(1,3);
insert into Relation_table values(1,4);
insert into Relation_table values(2,1);
insert into Relation_table values(4,6);
insert into Relation_table values(5,777);
insert into Relation_table values(5,898);
insert into Relation_table values(11,9);
```

Results:
Group1: 1,2,3,4,6
Group2: 5 (no references with others)
Group3: 9,11

777 and 898 don't belong to Table1.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use array types to accomplish this.

First remove duplicate relations:

```
with recursive combine as (
  select distinct least(id_element, id_secondary_element) as lid, 
         greatest(id_element, id_secondary_element) as rid
    from relation_table
),
```

Then group in both directions.  One using the smaller `id` value and the other using the larger `id` value.  Aggregate these into `int[]` and include the base `id` by prepending or appending depending on the aggregation.

```
exploded as (
  select lid, lid||array_agg(rid order by rid) as members
    from combine
   group by lid
  union 
  select rid, array_agg(lid order by lid)||rid as members
    from combine
   group by rid
),
```

The recursion step uses the array overlap `&&` operator to find and join groups together.  The `rpath` is necessary to prevent infinite looping.

```
iter as (
  select members[1] as first_member, members, array[members[1]] as rpath
    from exploded e
  union all
  select i.first_member, i.members || e.members, i.rpath||e.members[1]
    from iter i
         join exploded e
           on e.members && i.members
          and not e.members[1] = any(i.rpath)
),
```

Eliminate duplicate `id` values, eliminate `id` values that are not present in `table1`, and then keep only the distinct `members` arrays.

```
dedup as (
  select distinct array_agg(distinct m.member_id order by m.member_id) as members
    from iter i
         cross join lateral unnest(members) as m(member_id)
         join table1 on table1.id_element = m.member_id
   group by i.first_member
)
```

Assign `group_num` and return the results.

```
select rank() over (order by members[1]) as group_num,  members
  from dedup
 order by group_num;
```

[Working Fiddle with Original Data](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cFUUW2fCfPRX3AkAm9YxLJ/2).
[Working Fiddle with Failed Data](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cFUUW2fCfPRX3AkAm9YxLJ/3)

**Update**

Given your data size problems, you may want to use looping to tackle this:

```
 create or replace function group_consolidate() 
  returns table (group_num bigint, members int[]) 
as $$
  begin 
    create temp table group1 (id int not null, group_num int not null, primary key (id, group_num)) on commit drop;
    create temp table group2 (id int not null, group_num int not null, primary key (id, group_num)) on commit drop;
    
    with base as (
      select row_number() over (order by id_element) as group_num,
             id_element, id_secondary_element 
        from relation_table
    )
    insert into group1
    select base.id_element as id, base.group_num
      from base
     union
    select base.id_secondary_element as id, base.group_num
      from base
     order by 1, 2;
    
    while exists (select id from group1 group by id having count(*) > 1
                  union
                  select id from group2 group by id having count(*) > 1) loop

      raise notice 'Iteration %', clock_timestamp();
      truncate table group2;
      with reduce as (
        select a.group_num, min(b.group_num) new_group_num
          from group1 a
          join group1 b
            on a.id = b.id
           and a.group_num >=  b.group_num
         group by a.group_num
      )
      insert into group2
      select distinct g.id, r.new_group_num
        from group1 g
        join reduce r
          on r.group_num = g.group_num;

 
      truncate table group1;
      with reduce as (
        select a.group_num, min(b.group_num) new_group_num
          from group2 a
          join group2 b
            on a.id = b.id
           and a.group_num >=  b.group_num
         group by a.group_num
      )
      insert into group1
      select distinct g.id, r.new_group_num
        from group2 g
        join reduce r
          on r.group_num = g.group_num;


  end loop;
  return query select row_number() over (order by min(id)), array_agg(id order by id) as members
                 from group1
                      join table1 on table1.id_element = group1.id
                group by group1.group_num; 
end $$ language plpgsql;
```

Then, to use it:

```
select * from group_consolidate();
NOTICE:  Iteration 2020-08-26 10:22:55.925093-04
NOTICE:  Iteration 2020-08-26 10:22:55.926501-04
 group_num |    members    
-----------+---------------
         1 | {2,3,4,6,132}
         2 | {5}
         3 | {9,11}
(3 rows)
```

And here is a function that loops through the individual records using a technique I came across for matching groups.  This should be slower than the function, above, because of the `update` statements that accumulate, but I am interested in what the time difference would be for your dataset.

```
create or replace function onetab_consolidate() 
  returns table (group_num bigint, members int[])
as $$
  declare
    cur_loop cursor for
      select distinct array[
               least(id_element, id_secondary_element),
               greatest(id_element, id_secondary_element)
             ] as ary
        from relation_table
       order by ary; 
  begin
    create temporary table tempmatch (
      hid int not null primary key, 
      lid int not null
    ) on commit drop;

    for rec in cur_loop loop
      with new_rel as (
        select rec.ary[1] as lid, x.hid
          from unnest(rec.ary) as x(hid)
      ), upd_needed as (
        select distinct t.lid, min(least(t.lid, n.lid)) over () as newlid
          from tempmatch t
          join new_rel n on n.hid = t.hid 
      ), do_update as (
        update tempmatch
           set lid = un.newlid
          from upd_needed un 
         where un.lid = tempmatch.lid
           and un.newlid != tempmatch.lid
      )
      insert into tempmatch (hid, lid)
      select n.hid, coalesce(u.newlid, n.lid)
        from new_rel n
             cross join (select min(newlid) as newlid from upd_needed) u
      on conflict do nothing; 

    end loop;

    return query
      select dense_rank() over (order by min(hid)) as group_num,
             array_agg(hid order by hid) as members
        from tempmatch t
             join table1 on table1.id_element = t.hid
       group by lid
       order by group_num;
end $$ language plpgsql;
```

To use:

```
select * from onetab_consolidate();
 group_num |    members    
-----------+---------------
         1 | {2,3,4,6,132}
         2 | {5}
         3 | {9,11}
(3 rows)
```

To validate results from both using 6,000 random relations:

```
select * from group_consolidate() a join  (select * from onetab_consolidate()) b on a.group_num = b.group_num and a.members != b.members;
NOTICE:  Iteration 2020-08-27 06:38:11.170305-04
NOTICE:  Iteration 2020-08-27 06:38:11.257287-04
 group_num | members | group_num | members 
-----------+---------+-----------+---------
(0 rows)

Time: 3013.271 ms (00:03.013)

select count(*) from group_consolidate();
NOTICE:  Iteration 2020-08-27 06:38:25.112396-04
NOTICE:  Iteration 2020-08-27 06:38:25.188946-04
 count 
-------
  2073
(1 row)

Time: 210.014 ms

select count(*) from onetab_consolidate();
 count 
-------
  2073
(1 row)

Time: 2782.337 ms (00:02.782)
```

My testdata generator:

```
-- truncate table relation_table;
with randoms as (
  select floor(random() * 200000 + 1)::int as id1, 
         floor(random() * 200000 + 1)::int as id2
    from generate_series(1, 6000)
)
insert into relation_table
select * from randoms where id1 != id2
;

-- truncate table table1;
insert into table1
select *
  from generate_series(1,200000) where random() > 0.8;
```

Comment: Thank you Mike, but it doesn't work properly. If you change the table like this:

Comment: @qbexample  I have updated my answer to fix the mistake.

Comment: You are great Mike, I've tried with my example and it worked, but when I tested it on production (Table1 has 2.000 rows and Relation_table 28000) within 20 minutes it didn't finish. Is there any arrangement?

Comment: @qbexample  This approach might be too slow.  What is the result of `select count(*) from relation_table r join table1 t1 on t1.id_element = r.id_element join table1 t2 on t2.id_element = r.id_secondary_element` ?  Is the result significantly smaller than 28,000?

Comment: @qbexample  Please try the query here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cFUUW2fCfPRX3AkAm9YxLJ/4  It reduces the number of base elements in the `iter` CTE and ignores any `relation_table` records with values not found in `table1`.  If this is still too slow with your data, then there is another approach that uses looping and temporary tables.

Comment: unfortunatly the result is 27000. In the previous version, also if it didn't work properly had a really fast answer

Comment: @qbexample  The new link in my last comment tries to reduce the number of records somewhat.  When you run it, try running the CTEs one-by-one starting from the top to see how many records are coming back to see if something is obviously wrong with one of the steps.  You can comment out the rest of the query and put `select * from combine;` after the first CTE, for instance.

Comment: could it be easier if we add a column to Table1 with the group that ID_ELEMENT it belongs to?

Comment: 26987 after the first, after 35721 on exploded and it stopped working on ITER.

Comment: @qbexample  Please try this query to see how `biggest` does:  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cFUUW2fCfPRX3AkAm9YxLJ/4

Comment: @qbexample  With those rowcounts, you may want to try a looping approach.  I added a function example to my answer.

Comment: Mike, it looks like you are taking it personally :) I tried this https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cFUUW2fCfPRX3AkAm9YxLJ/4  the outcome was Error SQL [53100]: ERROR: could not write to tuplestore temporary file: No space left on device.

Comment: tomorrow morning (here is 10 pm) I'll try what you add after that. Thank you so much.

Comment: @qbexample  Please comment on whether the functions work for you.  I honest-to-goodness was working on this same problem in a different context yesterday which is why I am taking it personally :-)

Comment: I updated my answer with the timing of the two different approaches and the "quality" of the results. The second is much slower but no duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Mike,

Always with the same test I found duplicates:

select unnest(members),count(*) from test_group_consolidate group by unnest(members) having count(*) > 1 order by unnest(members);

```
INSERT INTO table2 (id_element) VALUES 
(19983)
,(20458)
,(20176)
,(19659)
,(567413)
,(19892)
,(5932)
,(20484)
,(20261)
,(19988)
,(19939)
,(20137)
;

INSERT INTO relation_table2 (id_element,id_secondary_element) VALUES 
(347133,346261)
,(95290,224342)
,(244702,204657)
,(97183,462539)
,(48864,48866)
,(86370,62853)
,(71824,77285)
,(477616,574296)
,(19659,20176)
,(516462,517132)
,(286373,340871)
,(57720,94328)
,(150074,412364)
,(499547,489631)
,(509899,367403)
,(341161,300297)
,(273910,241434)
,(261169,499283)
,(420699,420174)
,(574293,113781)
,(20176,567413)
,(26698,26258)
,(293765,293832)
,(485842,203903)
,(21233,28963)
,(218337,507312)
,(97183,97155)
,(563319,113781)
,(574293,124609)
,(423925,475583)
,(199786,201773)
,(33979,34823)
,(415817,341161)
,(19939,5932)
,(342705,343841)
,(77728,68220)
,(565348,136420)
,(289726,292819)
,(100574,42377)
,(27237,21147)
,(99398,99560)
,(365933,366012)
,(19659,20458)
,(321947,479974)
,(97183,97795)
,(91186,470477)
,(97965,58131)
,(367403,107286)
,(204123,495141)
,(99560,98583)
,(268360,495097)
,(97726,100574)
,(133571,134626)
,(503106,517592)
,(29369,33979)
,(97184,470462)
,(477116,489806)
,(136815,137227)
,(305482,305481)
,(23591,32745)
,(139195,139497)
,(100179,99398)
,(510076,322241)
,(548956,503410)
,(510743,518816)
,(475545,495703)
,(203925,204950)
,(457781,454316)
,(99398,99521)
,(446427,449889)
,(300297,341161)
,(218337,219036)
,(432788,432627)
,(47098,47001)
,(328419,340259)
,(20176,20137)
,(305348,286449)
,(516464,516463)
,(491821,473827)
,(507312,219036)
,(417130,186087)
,(39395,49318)
,(321888,323168)
,(365933,365880)
,(344847,345201)
,(367701,367403)
,(323168,321888)
,(491821,203540)
,(23591,31941)
,(342705,342159)
,(565348,136419)
,(100179,98583)
,(485842,324334)
,(20176,19988)
,(113781,563319)
,(47606,46939)
,(403537,351085)
,(353592,349450)
,(218349,218230)
,(518775,77285)
,(241538,273910)
,(285413,475114)
,(293765,328419)
,(91092,90107)
,(21726,22420)
,(265849,267666)
,(142561,134537)
,(514190,500724)
,(246838,246808)
,(200346,504095)
,(114759,135208)
,(90479,304912)
,(90628,494151)
,(22142,139497)
,(322651,497643)
,(496564,497368)
,(275738,241538)
,(493766,493247)
,(202552,489441)
,(574293,574295)
,(23591,23611)
,(465858,465548)
,(423925,424999)
,(241538,241434)
,(554660,30026)
,(100179,99521)
,(493363,493252)
,(417062,344313)
,(22855,565862)
,(462572,514469)
,(199786,198405)
,(458396,443427)
,(20176,19659)
,(200461,204853)
,(421619,396140)
,(287978,287881)
,(417062,344265)
,(517132,516463)
,(420327,420149)
,(200461,203137)
,(21726,21367)
,(275738,42723)
,(246838,246807)
,(417615,107117)
,(489419,88552)
,(30767,34823)
,(136987,137044)
,(150074,509467)
,(244702,475544)
,(103430,473827)
,(47573,47668)
,(129917,107117)
,(460567,460210)
,(201298,483702)
,(420327,420904)
,(459867,455799)
,(19659,19983)
,(523586,577430)
,(458396,449326)
,(28379,32745)
,(515377,489087)
,(23618,23646)
,(366405,366481)
,(410236,411683)
,(2026,113474)
,(499547,493187)
,(366405,366595)
,(21726,21876)
,(420327,420603)
,(322651,323255)
,(94644,102164)
,(286373,413743)
,(499547,493473)
,(516464,516462)
,(420768,420053)
,(20176,19892)
,(20176,19983)
,(107117,129917)
,(174987,439505)
,(66640,491408)
,(205695,486233)
,(203925,514528)
,(482833,204591)
,(427434,156566)
,(338116,476809)
,(88296,89599)
,(418928,417615)
,(487856,32108)
,(417615,129711)
,(99398,98583)
,(107117,129711)
,(108003,134564)
,(321947,479122)
,(415817,414664)
,(513001,513000)
,(3133,327745)
,(200580,224609)
,(21032,21032)
,(136419,136420)
,(19070,21700)
,(94464,98352)
,(81670,293766)
,(473827,103430)
,(203049,203051)
,(109648,105403)
,(42372,105547)
,(23076,23455)
,(475545,475541)
,(432982,432842)
,(73646,161680)
,(343935,344110)
,(416184,186087)
,(474300,433800)
,(421619,375601)
,(420699,304138)
,(95290,224344)
,(71824,77728)
,(21726,21583)
,(565348,140235)
,(77285,77728)
,(517531,223984)
,(236707,35523)
,(33979,30767)
,(200794,197748)
,(260719,50593)
,(423925,423928)
,(156566,427434)
,(366737,366736)
,(517132,516462)
,(487856,495153)
,(420768,458544)
,(516466,516464)
,(375601,396140)
,(347357,347725)
,(23824,27867)
,(292819,296716)
,(77285,68220)
,(344847,343789)
,(246838,246809)
,(445993,445994)
,(32159,33628)
,(102968,489054)
,(95745,91692)
,(23591,25927)
,(411683,410236)
,(88296,502544)
,(458396,449328)
,(200580,188106)
,(129917,129711)
,(338671,338380)
,(574293,8497)
,(95081,324093)
,(47573,501048)
,(30767,571281)
,(265502,273910)
,(423925,423926)
,(30643,28568)
,(513532,484413)
,(434075,382798)
,(367701,107286)
,(47606,47381)
,(26950,8339)
,(324048,503526)
,(95892,328375)
,(413108,413108)
,(97726,96844)
,(517531,495600)
,(417130,416184)
,(19659,20261)
,(493337,493252)
,(512127,457953)
,(87999,93566)
,(47573,47617)
,(236707,228537)
,(273910,275738)
,(492781,88103)
,(274868,565862)
,(173062,182262)
,(419087,421399)
,(516463,517132)
,(293766,293832)
,(246806,246808)
,(99398,100179)
,(370190,57160)
,(97184,97948)
,(87999,93602)
,(200461,203213)
,(139195,142437)
,(71824,77332)
,(574293,477616)
,(253935,274118)
,(516463,516464)
,(195245,191285)
,(19659,19988)
,(290057,66437)
,(30767,33979)
,(516464,517132)
,(101121,311967)
,(97965,97726)
,(150074,150224)
,(133537,235654)
,(420768,420851)
,(32492,32489)
,(123929,479086)
,(260659,249872)
,(139195,139109)
,(200346,201929)
,(203925,201567)
,(287907,290531)
,(273910,237094)
,(26698,26950)
,(482833,204590)
,(28369,32215)
,(554660,555585)
,(56832,102880)
,(237745,242271)
,(288015,346642)
,(476809,354274)
,(416920,434467)
,(458396,451732)
,(95290,93176)
,(224206,514616)
,(197748,202849)
,(491821,130394)
,(445993,457899)
,(461880,467496)
,(199786,203205)
,(204590,204591)
,(517482,43030)
,(22142,139109)
,(304138,420699)
,(286373,413310)
,(156468,214434)
,(474951,523171)
,(19659,20137)
,(475545,482639)
,(8497,113781)
,(139557,573654)
,(136987,142688)
,(477616,574293)
,(266925,267742)
,(475545,482784)
,(100574,42372)
,(97184,96583)
,(518775,71824)
,(499547,498554)
,(28369,500856)
,(32745,28379)
,(198405,324150)
,(89146,88556)
,(417062,418169)
,(445993,436630)
,(94644,68890)
,(506152,298762)
,(577208,577215)
,(300297,414664)
,(202027,244746)
,(344847,345200)
,(68220,8497)
,(204046,435570)
,(513532,536041)
,(493766,493245)
,(396140,375601)
,(477616,574295)
,(79045,101121)
,(462697,482834)
,(509899,367564)
,(30767,34824)
,(285413,283902)
,(33979,34824)
,(23591,23605)
,(445993,454818)
,(454229,454158)
,(408401,519901)
,(349599,414911)
,(516462,516464)
,(367701,367564)
,(42372,100574)
,(42372,45419)
,(20176,20484)
,(474299,433800)
,(23623,23646)
,(408401,514877)
,(19659,20484)
,(90628,498794)
,(21233,33922)
,(396140,421619)
,(366362,265350)
,(408401,499129)
,(185507,57731)
,(462572,506631)
,(287978,303277)
,(326098,311967)
,(150074,67052)
,(241538,265515)
,(461880,466048)
,(42377,188299)
,(23591,23250)
,(156468,182830)
,(477616,113781)
,(365933,365686)
,(366291,366362)
,(146144,483557)
,(99560,99398)
,(129842,119812)
,(275738,237094)
,(22142,142437)
,(420327,420599)
,(42372,193525)
,(240332,487601)
,(20176,19939)
,(241538,237094)
,(417615,418928)
,(34824,33979)
,(411022,415520)
,(100574,45419)
,(518775,77728)
,(105547,42377)
,(130390,494967)
,(367701,509899)
,(337777,51738)
,(460169,459865)
,(338671,451512)
,(420768,458513)
,(193525,33325)
,(275738,241434)
,(327745,3133)
,(462697,482835)
,(218230,218349)
,(93176,66352)
,(346903,346269)
,(246838,249319)
,(508571,224577)
,(366362,366291)
,(173062,184717)
,(136419,565348)
,(205695,190265)
,(344847,349900)
,(365933,365785)
,(417062,343964)
,(97726,13567)
,(473902,473904)
,(338116,354274)
,(365933,365894)
,(105547,105403)
,(23591,23632)
,(94269,100835)
,(418928,129711)
,(273910,265502)
,(199786,204990)
,(287907,303271)
,(237088,230540)
,(27562,516462)
,(517132,516466)
,(516463,516466)
,(134564,108003)
,(414664,341161)
,(105403,107492)
,(265849,267376)
,(420603,425301)
,(282962,282971)
,(26624,26052)
,(21726,20507)
,(236707,236575)
,(34824,29369)
,(95745,97497)
,(424999,423926)
,(136987,141964)
,(485965,523204)
,(129842,111596)
,(19207,21032)
,(487601,240332)
,(47606,47456)
,(71824,68220)
,(473827,198471)
,(77285,77332)
,(420768,458481)
,(100179,99560)
,(75839,93309)
,(88296,489548)
,(105547,107492)
,(577208,566644)
,(95081,513835)
,(47098,47085)
,(287907,289134)
,(136987,142561)
,(325714,324701)
,(94644,95892)
,(293766,81670)
,(365933,365877)
,(203925,202415)
,(474299,474300)
,(32492,32490)
,(445993,531028)
,(77728,77332)
,(375601,421619)
,(485965,521183)
,(517132,516464)
,(418928,107117)
,(29369,30767)
,(26698,26819)
,(408401,522095)
,(136987,137794)
,(199499,500811)
,(199786,202199)
,(516466,516463)
,(293765,348556)
,(105403,105547)
,(420768,420320)
,(434075,252448)
,(47573,47497)
,(200580,188122)
,(370190,470631)
,(346261,347133)
,(266925,483608)
,(26698,26530)
,(445993,455651)
,(235335,92784)
,(201298,472349)
,(136419,140235)
,(42372,42377)
,(289726,291294)
,(23618,23623)
,(474300,433891)
,(97935,481263)
,(416920,420108)
,(128348,129425)
,(555375,56238)
,(292671,168022)
,(324640,324291)
,(8497,68220)
,(23623,23618)
,(274868,22855)
,(71824,518775)
,(75839,87384)
,(518775,77332)
,(8497,574293)
,(202552,204673)
,(241920,244053)
,(424999,423928)
,(265350,247905)
,(516463,516462)
,(424999,475583)
,(516466,517132)
,(21726,21707)
,(170064,169024)
,(136815,133522)
,(202552,202653)
,(21726,21232)
,(509899,107286)
,(275738,273910)
,(330248,395840)
,(29369,34824)
,(292819,293766)
,(516464,516466)
,(420327,182568)
,(88296,89521)
,(288015,346641)
,(367403,367564)
,(26950,32160)
,(97726,42372)
,(341514,344891)
,(458396,459259)
,(290945,129917)
,(474951,324144)
,(56832,34347)
,(97726,58131)
,(420174,420699)
,(417062,344053)
,(508571,246277)
,(547443,34594)
,(266925,267051)
,(130390,508158)
,(342705,343519)
,(577430,523586)
,(20176,20458)
,(324640,482104)
,(517531,475013)
,(304138,303392)
,(445994,457899)
,(156468,156469)
,(354274,476809)
,(34824,34823)
,(23591,29516)
,(42377,144086)
,(23632,31941)
,(23618,20980)
,(51738,43325)
,(413310,202368)
,(447093,457251)
,(509899,367701)
,(88552,489419)
,(420768,458282)
,(548956,548977)
,(35316,493792)
,(477616,124609)
,(97184,98012)
,(101121,326098)
,(28369,28632)
,(403537,390953)
,(419087,418397)
,(202027,471268)
,(325714,481256)
,(474951,322651)
,(129917,417615)
,(19659,19892)
,(218180,218349)
,(102545,102535)
,(420768,303376)
,(287978,281150)
,(507312,218337)
,(32171,31506)
,(516466,516462)
,(366291,265350)
,(366291,265408)
,(268939,524032)
,(58131,73646)
,(508550,33809)
,(370190,330512)
,(268331,463164)
,(23455,23076)
,(424999,423925)
,(21700,19070)
,(474299,433891)
,(285413,305952)
,(516462,516463)
,(343964,344053)
,(347357,347190)
,(367403,509899)
,(22855,274868)
,(508868,500865)
,(218349,218180)
,(518775,68220)
,(33979,29369)
,(416184,417130)
,(29369,34823)
,(324481,510987)
,(105547,109648)
,(105547,45419)
,(381445,502788)
,(99560,99521)
,(474300,474299)
,(198405,199786)
,(510743,518818)
,(420768,458533)
,(290057,439384)
,(27237,17005)
,(342705,344770)
,(557407,569214)
,(99560,100179)
,(508571,482492)
,(199396,516942)
,(47606,47516)
,(23442,106434)
,(265502,265515)
,(237745,232760)
,(57720,435760)
,(515377,489086)
,(573654,577430)
,(188288,188295)
,(23591,26233)
,(241538,42723)
,(321947,495049)
,(97935,476554)
,(279121,411089)
,(204841,501427)
,(365933,365921)
,(508868,510077)
,(204959,503276)
,(322651,324442)
,(237088,242368)
,(412797,413108)
,(476564,492620)
,(421399,419087)
,(246838,246806)
,(30767,29369)
,(508571,243959)
,(90479,457779)
,(47573,47471)
,(273910,42723)
,(202552,524204)
,(23623,20980)
,(268331,267355)
,(201298,493465)
,(42372,282962)
,(265350,260659)
,(499547,493501)
,(5932,19939)
,(204529,202644)
,(516462,516466)
,(22142,139195)
,(97935,496138)
,(47606,47367)
,(292819,290932)
,(420699,303392)
,(574293,574296)
,(20176,20261)
,(275417,243034)
,(129917,418928)
,(109648,107492)
,(241538,275738)
,(483557,146144)
,(265350,249872)
,(366362,265408)
,(506803,524066)
,(253935,260779)
,(23591,28379)
,(344847,343326)
,(202552,204412)
,(34824,30767)
,(365933,365675)
,(455879,211842)
,(287978,304095)
,(265515,265502)
,(341161,414664)
,(366405,99235)
,(185571,187316)
,(474951,324481)
,(414664,300297)
,(458396,459486)
,(367403,367701)
,(23442,106893)
,(23632,26233)
,(241920,241922)
,(42372,105403)
,(508550,33573)
,(491821,494855)
;
```

you'll find out
19939 2 occurrencies
20176 2 occurrencies

like these:

```
|group_num           |members    |
|--------------------|-----------|
|3                   |
{5932,19939,20176}|
|10                   {19659,19892,19939,19983,19988,20137,20176,20261,20458,20484,567413}
```

Comment: I will take another look at the first function.  If you have some examples that showed up as duplicates, can you please add their `relation_table` rows?  As for any duplicates in the latter function, the structure of the temporary table makes duplicates impossible since that column is the primary key.

Comment: Sorry.  There was an error in the first function.  I have corrected it in my answer.  In the insert into table `group1` at the bottom of the loop it should be a `left join` back to the CTE.

Comment: @MikeOrganek it doesn't work, with the first function I've got a lot of duplicates. If you want I could send you two file with the create instances in order to help you testing your function.

Comment: I generated a random dataset.  I am working on the first function.  The second one looks to be correct, it just takes a long time to run.

Comment: I have the group function fixed.  It runs a lot faster on my test dataset and produces the same results as the much slower second function.  The updated code is in my answer, above.  I generated 99,998 random rows for `relation_table`, and it completed in 8 seconds.  With 60,000 rows, it completes in under 3 seconds.

Comment: I found same duplicates again, try these:

Comment: I am so sorry.  I had the wrong code in my answer.  I must have made a cut/paste error.  The correct function for `group_consolidate()` is now in my answer.

Comment: it looks like you really made it! Tomorrow I'll check again. How can I thank you?

Comment: You already did.  Sorry it took so long to get the fast one right.  Please let me know if you have any problems with it.  The exit condition on the loop guarantees that there will not be any duplicates.

Comment: Thank you so much Mike! I'd focus on the results of the 2 algorithms. It would be a little hard, because the members are in different orders.

Comment: I have normalized the ordering of results in both functions (small changes in the `return query` sections) and added a validation query and DML for generating test relations.  You may want to use CTAS instead of directly querying to validate.  Good luck with your project, and I hope to see you around here!  Comment if there's anything further you need.

Comment: thank you so much, I'm changing the profencies of the date adding validity dates like: the relation between a,b start 2020/01/01  and ends 2020/01/31 while b,c works between 2020/01/15 and 2020/07/31. a,b,c exists starting 2020/01/1 and ends 2020/07/31. if starts another relation  z,c between 2020/08/03 it doesn't belong to the same group (2 days discontinuity)